# Have to use back button twice in browsers (Firefox/Chrome/IE); extra # being added to URL

Tags: http, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

After experimenting with a handful of new addons for Firefox, I've managed to permanently foul up some settings.

Using certain sites (take Netflix for example), upon clicking into a details page for a movie, I'll notice the following CSS ID

```
#height1754
```

added onto the end of the URL. When I use the back button, the only thing that happens is the removal of the above suffix, while remaining on the same unwanted page.  A second click on the back button actually takes me back to the previous page.

I've heard of similar issues that were particular to IE, but haven't found anything involving all of them.

Any suggestions and/or explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that Netflix is just throwing that hash tag in for no reason now.  Something new, that I imagine will be corrected.

The fact that I installed a bunch of addons and changed settings was just a total and irritating coincidence that sent me off chasing a red herring...bollocks.

Thanks all.

**Update:**

They've actually fixed this now, and the extra hash has been eliminated.

Comment: It's not for "no reason".  See Dustin Laine's answer about hash tags. You clicked "into a details page" so the Back button backs you out. One click in, one click out.

Comment: No, one click in, two clicks out.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. That is a hash tag, and was traditionally used to link to and/or jump to an anchor in the page. The anchor saves in your history, which is why your first back link goes to the page without the hash.

Today it is also used to implement bookmarking and/or direct linking to pages with AJAX requests.